# Clear details stored in form

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have a user registration page, after entering all the details and successful account creation, I want to stay in the same page, but all the user entered details should be cleared

but if the registration is unsuccessful then all the user entered details should be retained.

which is the right way of achieving this?

is clearing all the values manually in code, the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewstate is maintained during postbacks. So, you can do a redirect to the same url if the registration is successful. Make sure that your databindings check for IsPostback.

Answer (score 2):

The state for the textboxes is maintained during postback, so you could clear them manually.

However Ingenu's answer suggest to use whats called the [PRG-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) which is an even better fit. In your case it goes like this:

1. On succesfull creation of an account, you should issue a redirect to the same page. The redirect will call your registration page as a GET request again, and clear all textboxes.
2. If the create is unsuccessfull, you should **NOT** redirect. So that the user stays on the same page with the textboxes still filled.

Comment: And before redirecting, set a querystring or session variable so that when the page is reloaded, a success message can be passed to the user.

Comment: @James: session retains for quite longer time, is there any way to send data to a page other than querystring?

Comment: @dotNETbeginner I tend to use `Session`, and then in `Page_Load` check whether it exists. If it does, I read its value and then delete the key from the Session so it doesn't persist.